# booting from a usb option not present Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, usb

I need to reinstall Ubuntu but I can't get the option to boot from usb.  I made my bootable usb drive.

When I re-start the computer, I have tried hitting F2, F8, F11, F12, ESC, and holding ESC for 3sec and then hitting F1.  If I hold shift, I enter grub2 but that just says Ubuntu, Advanced, mems test.

How can I get to booting from the USB?

I am currently on Ubuntu 13.04 using a Toshiba Satellite.

Comment: Boot from USB can only be selected prior to the os loading so os isn't relevant. Contact your manufacturer and ask How to changeyyour boot order

Comment: Power on self test, stage 1 actually so I edited the comment when I realised my mistake. POST is a technical term used with computers

Comment: It's in your BIOS and no you don't have to contact your manufacturing if you know How to access your BIOS

Comment: tried ESC for the boot menu? also, dont use a usb 3.0 port; use a usb 2.0 instead for usb installs

Comment: @D0rf I will try ESC but that was never it before--maybe this time.

Comment: @D0rf that didn't work either.

Comment: is the USB drive recognized in BIOS? if so, give it boot priority and boot from there, even if you temporarily have to remove other devices from boot.

Comment: @D0rf I can't enter bios no matter what I try.

Comment: during boot, at POST you should see a toshiba logo. press TAB so you can see the "text" behind it. is there any mention to what key to press?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to hold down F2 then I was giving the option to hit F2 or F12 for BIOS and boot options respectively.